# Determining whether a given set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I was asked the following question:

> Determine if the following set is a vector space:
> $$W=\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}p\\q\\r\\s\\\end{matrix}\right]:\begin{matrix}-3p+2q=-s\\p=-s+3r\\\end{matrix}\right\}$$

I know the answer is yes and you can show it by showing that W is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_4$. But, I have no idea how to show that, or in general how to determine if a set is a vector space. I am interested in understanding so that I can apply it to future questions, not just so that I can answer this question.

Comment: A subspace of a vector space is itself a vector space; that's kind of the whole motivation behind the definition.

Comment: You pretty much have to walk through the vector space axioms.  When you're talking about a subset of something that you already know is a vector space, many of the axioms (such as the distributive property) are obvious because the subset "inherits" them from the larger vector space it lives within.  But you have to check closure properties, such as making sure that every sum of two elements of your subset is also in your subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general approach to show that a set $M$ is a vector space is to find an already known vector space $(X,K,+,\cdot)$, where $X$ is the set of vectors, $K$ a field and $M\subset X$.

Then $M$ is a vector subspace (and thus a vector space), under the operations of $X$, if for every $x,y\in M$ and any $\alpha , \beta \in K$ we have $\alpha \cdot x + \beta \cdot y\in M$. You can check that if this is true then $M$ is vector space.

So to your specific example, and I will refer to $W$ as the set you have given:

We have $W\subset \mathbb{R}^{4}$, so let us endow $W$ with the operations of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Pick any $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and let
$$x = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\\ x_{3}\\ x_{4}\end{bmatrix}  \quad y = \begin{bmatrix}y_{1}\\ y_{2}\\ y_{3}\\ y_{4}\end{bmatrix}$$
be two arbitrary members of $W$, then:
$$\alpha x + \beta y  = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha x_{1} + \beta y_{1}\\ \alpha x_{2} + \beta y_{2}\\ \alpha x_{3} + \beta y_{3}\\ \alpha x_{4}+\beta y_{4}\end{bmatrix}.$$

We need to check that this new vector is indeed in $W$. From the description of $W$ this would mean that $$-3(\alpha x_{1} + \beta y_{1})+2(\alpha x_{2} + \beta y_{2})=-(\alpha x_{4} + \beta y_{4}) \tag{1}$$
and also
$$(\alpha x_{1} + \beta y_{1})=-(\alpha x_{4} + \beta y_{4})+3(\alpha x_{3} + \beta y_{3})\tag{2}.$$
Starting with $(1)$ we know that since $x,y\in W\subset \mathbb{R}^{4}$ that
\begin{align*}-3(\alpha x_{1} + \beta y_{1})+2(\alpha x_{2} + \beta y_{2})&=\alpha(-3x_{1}+2x_{2})+\beta(-3y_{1}+2y_{2})\\
&= \alpha(-x_{4})+\beta (-y_{4})\\
&= -(\alpha x_{4}+ \beta y_{4}). \end{align*}

We now go on to $(2)$:
\begin{align*}(\alpha x_{1} + \beta y_{1}) &= \alpha(x_{1})+ \beta(y_{2})\\
&=\alpha(-x_{4}+3x_{3})+\beta(-y_{4}+3y_{3})\\
&=-(\alpha x_{4} + \beta y_{4})+3(\alpha x_{3}+\beta y_{3}).\end{align*}

We therefore conclude, since $(1)$ and $(2)$ are satisfied, that $\alpha x + \beta y \in W$, $W$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and therefore $W$ is a vector space.

I will end on that you can check that $\alpha \cdot x\in W$ and then $x+y\in W$ respectively as long as you let the vectors and scalars be arbitrary members of their respective sets. For more examples I recommend the wikipedia page on [Linear subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace).

Answer (score 0):

You know it's a subset of $\Bbb R^4$.  So it will be a vector space if and only if it is a subspace.  You can use the subspace criterion:  closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

This can be done "by hand", or, in this case, you can use the "trick" of noting that $W$ is the kernel of the transformation from $\Bbb R^4$ to $\Bbb R^2$ whose matrix rel the standard basis is $\begin{pmatrix} -3&2&0&1\\1&0&-3&1\end{pmatrix}$.

It is easy to see that the kernel of a linear transformation is always a subspace of the domain (use the subspace criterion again), and hence a vector space in its own right.